# How do you make two color gradient lines in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, gradient

I tried it with two gradient overlays, but the result is just white

[image]

Any suggestion? Thanks in advance

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120988/discussion-on-question-by-agil-ga-how-do-you-make-two-color-gradient-lines-in-ph).

Answer (score 3):

You can use Gradient overlay. Make sure all your lines are grouped or they are part of one layer.

Then right click (or from *fx* button) over your layer or group (your artwork), select Blending Options and use desired gradient overlay, like this:

[image]

[image]

Alternatively, you can create a new gradient layer and use clipping mask.

[image]

---

If you want gradient over your background, same techniques will work. Just make sure the gradient effect is applied and is shown under the layer name (highlighted by yellow arrow below). Also cross check the opacity of your *grunge-wall-texture* layer. It shouldn't be 0%:

[image]

**Notes:**

1. It might be possible you're not *inside* Gradient overlay menu once you open Blending options. Make sure the Gradient Overlay button is *highlighted* (see yellow outline in above screenshots) so you see the tools related to that only, on right side. Even when you have checked the Gradient Overlay, that menu button should be clicked upon so you get options.
2. The question is a bit unclear to me. So I've tried to help solve the possible problems that I think OP is facing.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120989/discussion-on-answer-by-vikas-how-do-you-make-two-color-gradient-lines-in-photos).